# Postgres Update query plan spends time somewhere not identifiable

Tags: postgresql

I am updating a table in postgres using the following query

```
UPDATE "people"
SET    "date" = '2024-01-29T11:20:54.974582+00:00' :: timestamptz
WHERE  ( condition )
```

Query Plan

```
UPDATE on people (cost=0.70..175.54 rows=1 width=439) (actual time=8734.732..8734.732 rows=0 loops=1) 
-> INDEX scan using  people_idx ON commission (cost=0.70..175.54 rows=1 width=439) (actual time=0.146..217.472 rows=1610 loops=1) 
   INDEXCOND: (condition)
```

As you can see the filter using index scan got completed in 217 milliseconds but the updates started only on 8734 milliseconds, how to find where the in-between time is spent also I enabled log_lock_waits and did not notice any lock-related logs, please help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

`log_lock_waits` will only record locks that last longer than `deadlock_timeout`, which defaults to one second. You should try to lower the latter parameter; perhaps then you can see a lock.

Other reasons for a slow `UPDATE` that come to my mind are

1. many indexes (in particular GIN indexes)
2. triggers (they show up in `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`, but you chose not to show the whole output)
3. another possibility would be JIT, but unless you modified the optimizer parameters, that shouldn't kick in for a statement that is estimated to be that cheap

Comment: regarding deadlock_timeout. if the default value is 1s, in the above case the wait time was close to 8s, so the lock related logs should have shown up am I right?.
I checked the config for deadlock_timeout and it was default, we are using was RDS aurora engine.

Comment: You are right. But it could be several small waits that accumulate to eight seconds.

Comment: When you say several small waits, if there are multiple queries in the waiting queue due to the lock and each query releases its lock in less than one second, there might be no lock-related logs, is that what you mean? I thought the engine checks the overall waiting time of query.

Comment: Execution will block whenever a row that should be locked is already locked, which can happen many times. The `deadlock_timeout` doesn't time the execution of a query, it starts ticking when the first session is waiting for a lock and gets reset when nobody waits for a lock.